# How to fix my micro SD card that became a read-only memory card?

Tags: applications, external-sd, sd-card

Since the Android external memory card has turned to read only (also known as SD card write-protected) all of a sudden, I can no longer add, write, or delete things from it.

How to fix the SD card that mounted as read only?

Is there an application to solve this problem?

Comment: copy files to another MicroSD Card. in case of adoptable-storage use gddrescue for 1:1 clone